# How to make function simple

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, refactoring

Maybe delete some logical Operators, make a "Check function "?

Or connect some logical in one piece?

> // Function

```
function getTicketPrice(childNumber,adultNumber){

  if (childNumber > 2 && adultNumber > 2) {
    return "-";
  }
    if (childNumber == 2 && adultNumber == 3) {
    return "-";
  }
    if (childNumber == 3 && adultNumber == 2) {
    return "-";
  }  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Ticket");  
  var row = getTicketPriceChild(childNumber, sheet);
  var col = getTicketPriceAdult(adultNumber, sheet);

    if (row >-1 && col === undefined) {
    return "-";
  }
    if (row === undefined && col >-1) {
    return "-";
  }    

  var value = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();

    if(value > 1){
    return value;
  } else {
    return '-';
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to simplify the function?

Comment: Put all the `if` conditions together so you have only one block for `-` at the top. Same for the two `if`s in the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function getTicketPrice(childNumber, adultNumber) {
  if ((childNumber > 2 && adultNumber > 2) || (childNumber == 2 && adultNumber == 3) || (childNumber == 3 && adultNumber == 2))
    return "-";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName('Ticket');
  const row = getTicketPriceChild(childNumber, sheet);
  const col = getTicketPriceAdult(adultNumber, sheet);

  if ((row > -1 && col === undefined) || (row === undefined && col > -1))
    return "-";

  const value = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  return value > 1 ? value : "-"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I just deleted my answer as it was incorrect

Comment: @Konstantin Baklaev , Thank you!

Comment: `(childNumber && adultNumber > 2)` should be `childNumber > 2 && adultNumber > 2)` - the first expression treats `childNumber` value of  1 as `true`.

Comment: you're right i corrected the answer, thx you for attentiveness!